# Randomizing Items and Cycling Through List (Python)

Tags: python, list

Y'all, I'm trying to alleviate some of my work in migrating from a face-to-face teaching environment to one that is remote for at least the next three months. To this end, I am trying to create randomized lists of eligible vocabulary words for quizzes. I can have it generate up to eighteen sets of words for an identical number of quizzes, but I seem to be fumbling with checking whether the randomly selected word is already part of that quiz, i.e. I am getting a ton of repeats. Since one word is taught per day, this means the first biweekly quiz will have ten eligible words; the second, twenty words; the third, thirty words; etc. Please see the code below, and thank you in advance for your help!

```
import random

all_words = "salutation feasible obnoxious depict resolve surmise assumption kindle intimidate jurisdiction allege characterize similar novice perceive condemn avid concise quench abrasive inevitable universal exonerate endeavor competent bamboozle simulate jeopardize prospective mutiny ubiquity integrate prevalent audacious reverberate corroborate feasible theory devour calamity boisterous amiss bizarre punctual simultaneous proprietor component famished significant conclude abdicate boycott consult rebuff eccentric imperative confront naive tirade ludicrous conscientious inhabitant confiscate admonish acknowledge embark prominent evoke libel modify imminent affiliation dawdle encompass indifferent perspective bias vitality necessity connotation despondent grieve gruesome perish devious sovereign propaganda construct prudent viewpoint liaison negligent relinquish mitigate formidable chronological commence ambiguous suspense consistent temperament impel assimilate gracious estimate apathy resilient opposition elapse killjoy obsolete signify satire hypothesis tumult harmonious fictitious authentic anonymous attribute procedure conclusive thrive capable interrogate legendary spontaneous addict merge evidence mandatory demeanor rebel despicable belligerent agitate oppress rebuke anarchy recur consecutive derogatory anthology valor elegant transit acquire authority contrast tentative profound specific exposition conjecture exuberant diversity abhor irate haughty irrelevant cause hospitable quaint inspire derive impartial industrious pseudonym omit prediction source apprehend bisect focus antagonize adequate bewildered correspond precise eligible".split(" ")

for week in range(1, 2):
    print("---------------------")
    print("Quiz #" + str(week))
    print("---------------------")
    print("Word\t\tID")
    print("---------------------")

    for word in range(1, 10+1):
        random_words = []
        
        random_word = all_words[random.randrange(0, (week*10))]
        
        # checks to see if random word is already
        # part of the words on the upcoming quiz
        if random_word not in random_words:
            random_words.append(random_word)

        # test to see if any of the ids match
        # and that they fall within the eligible
        # range for vocab words already taught
        for test in random_words:
            print('{:15} {}'.format(test, all_words.index(test)+1))
    print("---------------------")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to try using `random.sample(all_words, 10)` and loop over to extend the output for subsequent weeks (changing 10 to the desired number of words). You will need to `import random` first.

Comment: FANTASTIC!! Thank you so much for sharing this with me. I ended up using the following: random_words = random.sample(all_words[0:week*10], 10)